# Gif validation failed: likes: Cast to Array failed for value "1" at path "likes"

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having a trouble while saving some data to mongoose database. You can find all the information of my model and controller. The problem is that I want to keep an array of users who liked a specific post, therefore I am holding their ObjectId's in the array, plus I have specified in the model as `[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]`.

I log the before and after manipulating the data and it gives me the desired output:

```
The likes value of the found gif:  []
Document Id is:  59c3122632af313ff3a9d962
User not liked yet!
New likes value:  ["59c3122632af313ff3a9d962"]
```

Still, it tells give me the following Validation Error:

```
ValidationError: Gif validation failed: likes: Cast to Array failed for value "1" at path "likes"
```

Would appreciate if you point out what is wrong in my code. Best!

Here is my controller:

```
export function handleLike(req, res) {
  // We will need the uid of the liking user and cuid of the liked gif
  Gif.findOne({ cuid: req.body.cuid }).exec((err, gif) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
      console.log('Error while the gif is being found.')
    }
    console.log('The likes value of the found gif: ', gif.likes)
    User.findOne({ uid: req.body.uid }).exec((e, user) => {
      if (e) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
        console.log('Error while user is being found.')
      }
      const userDocumentId = user._id
      console.log('Document Id is: ', userDocumentId)
      const isUserLiked = gif.likes.includes(userDocumentId)
      console.log('User not liked yet!')
      if (isUserLiked) {
        const newLikeArray = gif.likes.filter(like => like !== userDocumentId)
        gif.set({ likes: newLikeArray })
      } else {
        const newLikeArray = gif.likes.push(userDocumentId)
        gif.set({ likes: newLikeArray })
      }
      console.log('New likes value: ', gif.likes)
      gif.save((error, newGif) => {
        console.log(gif)
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).send(error)
          console.log('Error while saving the gif.')
          console.log(error)
        }
        res.send(newGif)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Here is my model:

```
const GifSchema = Schema({
  // In case there may occur a problem with Google Cloud Upload, make URL required!
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  crop_start: { type: Number, required: true },
  crop_finish: { type: Number, required: true },
  meme: String,
  tags: [String],
  url: { type: String },
  cuid: { type: 'String' },
  uploaded: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  customWidth: Number,
  customHeight: Number,
})
```

And the console output and the error is as given below:

```
The likes value of the found gif:  []
Document Id is:  59c3122632af313ff3a9d962
User not liked yet!
New likes value:  ["59c3122632af313ff3a9d962"]
{ _id: 59c3d98b65fcef2f9ad60230,
  owner: 59c3122632af313ff3a9d962,
  customHeight: 180,
  customWidth: 320,
  url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/de9nq41ka/video/upload/v1506007487/js4pnuezelrtitxnbovd.mp4',
  cuid: 'cj7ulxyg40000eixhum3hjqbr',
  id: 'gmn1no0lEuk',
  crop_start: 0.35503994850158693,
  crop_finish: 2.407723893188477,
  meme: '',
  __v: 0,
  likes: [ 59c3122632af313ff3a9d962 ],
  disabled: false,
  uploaded: 2017-09-21T15:23:55.653Z,
  tags: [ 'hayvan', 'tatlı', 'komik', 'eglenceli' ] }
Error while saving the gif.
{ ValidationError: Gif validation failed: likes: Cast to Array failed for value "1" at path "likes"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:57:23)
    at formatValue (util.js:357:36)
    at inspect (util.js:221:10)
    at format (util.js:98:24)
    at Console.log (console.js:127:21)
    at /home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/src/server/controllers/gif.controller.js:101:19
    at /home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3835:16
    at /home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:167:17
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
  errors:
   { likes:
      { CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "1" at path "likes"
          at CastError (/home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:27:11)
          at model.Document.set (/home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:766:7)
          at model._handleIndex (/home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:598:14)
          at model.Document.set (/home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:558:24)
          at /home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/src/server/controllers/gif.controller.js:93:13
          at /home/ugur/Desktop/gifl.io/react-webpack/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2922:18
          at <anonymous>
          at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
        message: 'Cast to Array failed for value "1" at path "likes"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"1"',
        kind: 'Array',
        value: 1,
        path: 'likes',
        reason: [Object] } },
  _message: 'Gif validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong argument, as if you were using react's `setState`:

> ```
> gif.set({ likes: newLikeArray })
> ```

According to the [API](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set), you should pass the `path` and `value` separately:

> ```
> Document#set(path, val, [type], [options])
> ```
>
> Sets the value of a path, or many paths.
>   Parameters:
>   path  path or object of key/vals to set
>   val  the value to set
>   [type]  optionally specify a type for "on-the-fly" attributes
>   [options]  optionally specify options that modify the behavior of the set

Either use:

```
gif.set('likes', newLikeArray)
```

or:

```
gif.likes = newLikeArray
```

Comment: Giving me the same error.In the following website the set() function is used in the way that I have used. It's strange... Check it out: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html | They used as   tank.set({ size: 'large' });